# achieving custom layout using jquery masonry

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am told that this is impossible but I don't see how. I am trying to achieve a custom layout using the *[jquery masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)* plugin. If anyone has an idea or a different plugin that they would believe is better then please let me know. I have posted this to 5 plugin developers of masonry plugins and all told me it was impossible. The basic idea is to have new blog posts auto post to a wall in a completely random pattern.

What do you think?

*IMAGE BELOW HAS BEEN UPDATED

[layout http://perfectss.com/wp-content/uploads/resources/blog-layout.png](http://perfectss.com/wp-content/uploads/resources/blog-layout.png)

Comment: masonry is possible to use in wordpress but you are trying to create a cloud which is centered... what is the main goal? are you generally trying to use masonry with wordpress or you got that part covered and just trying to create this specific layout? what have you got so far in terms of code?

Comment: I have used the jQuery masonry plugin to create a Wordpress plugin, so that part is fine. You are correct, I am trying to achieve a cloud like layout using that plugin. My code is essentially the jQuery masonry plugin with some added php for Wordpress function. I didn't want to get to deep into it if it wasn't possible. Any suggestions or direction??

Comment: I have updated the image above for better clairity

Comment: i see (nice graphics ;))... have been testing on my local system and thus far no luck... got to go to work but will retry in the evening ;)

Comment: Hey thanks alot, let me know if you have any luck.